# hot to add one month to the required column by substracting one day from it in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, intervals, datediff, dateadd

I have a column as date. In that column I have a value as '2016-05-06' I want a result in such manner that it will add the complete one month into this column. But it should return a one day before result.

So when i execute the query like:

```
select date,(date + interval '1 month') as new_column 
from batchproduct_info;
```

it give me the result as:

```
date           new_column
2016-05-06  2016-06-06 00:00:00
2016-05-07  2016-06-07 00:00:00
```

But I want result in this format:

```
date           new_column
2016-05-06  2016-06-05 00:00:00
2016-05-07  2016-06-06 00:00:00
```

i.e it should subtract the one day from one month.

Answer (score 3):

This is a solution to your problem:

```
select date, (date + '1 month'::interval - '1 day'::interval) as new_column
from   batchproduct_info;
```